# How do I get a selector from its name?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I have an NSString containing the name of a selector I would like to call with performSelector.  How can I get a reference to the selector from the string?

Answer (score 16):

[`NSSelectorFromString(name)`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString)

Comment: Easy like objective-c easy ...?

Comment: Yet, I was about a min off from being 1st... sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Could use NSSelectorFromString.

Probably inefficient as parameterizing a SEL is preferred.

Comment: How do you parameterize a SEL?